# Use string as a button value

Tags: c#, string, button

Is there any way i could use string or int as a button value?

I'm using MS visual studio and i have various buttons on my form.

I would like to do something like this:

```
string value = "1";

if (button(value).Text == "X")
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: button(value) ...what are you trying to achieve `button1.Text` ?

Comment: Have a look at `Tag` property

Comment: Yes. I would like to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do an action on click

You can handle multiple buttons like this and use your `if` there, or just make separate events for them

```
btn1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_Click);
btn2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_Click);
btn3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_Click);

...

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var button = sender as button;
    // if here if you need it
    //if(button.Tag == 'X') or if (button.Text == 'X') 
    //{
    //    do something
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //}
}
```

[Button.OnClick Method (EventArgs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="one" id="One" onclick= "click(this.value)'"/>
```

where **click(this.value)** is function on javascript

```
function click(x)
{
    //x is value from onclick button
}
```